# How to fune-tune and deploy ChatGPT on Cloud?

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3, chatgpt-api, fine-tuning, gpt-4

I know - how to fine-tune the ChatGPT. However, I not able to find out - How we can deploy the fine-tuned model in our server/cloud?
Can you anyone please help me with these?

I've created the fine-tune model of ChatGPT. But I'm not getting - how to that model can be in my system/server/cloud?

Answer (score 0):

As of August 2023, you cannot move a fine-tuned `gpt-3` or `gpt-3.5` model into your own cloud. The model can only be accessed via the `OpenAI API` or on their playground. You still own the data used to fine-tune the model and the data going in and out of the model.
However, the model will be private to you and can only be access via your `API key` and your `Fine-tuned model ID`